# Software RAID to hardware RAID, can it be done?

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, best-practices

Can it be done ... well.

(For the record, I did not set this server up.)

In my server there are 4 disks. 3 of them are in a software RAID5, and 1 has the OS installed. I want to buy a RAID controller, 4 new HDs and set up a hardware RAID5. If possible, I'd like to just image the current setup, and use it to build my new one.

My questions are: Can I image a 3 disk RAID5 to 4 disk RAID5? Are there problems with this? What is considered best practice for your OS. To have it on a separate disk like it currently is, or to install it on the RAID5?

Thank you. I can clarify anything. I'm not sure what other info might be pertinent.

Edit - I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* go through all manner of hoops to do this, or you could do yourself a favour and just backup your OS & data, put in the new controller/array and restore. It'll save you SO much head/heartache.

Comment: This this this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for being dense, but backup/restore with what? I have backup exec, but I use it mostly for backing up shared drives. Very simple process. I'm basically a helpdesk guy with some extra responsibility. In other words, if I mess up this server, I won't be able to fix it.

Comment: Back it up with backup exec, as if your server had catastrophic failure and had to be restored from bare metal.

Comment: @gtaylor85, you don't mention your operating system, maybe let us know and we may be able to help more. Also if you can afford the small drop in usable disk space and all 4 of your disks are the same then consider one big RAID 10 array over the R0+R5 setup you currently have.

Comment: Thanks Chopper. I'll look at that as an option. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: IIRC W2K8 has a nice backup thing built in (no expert on this software though sorry).